# Setting TLS options for Docker as Environment Variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I've got the local docker daemon running using certificates and I can list all the running containers using the very long winded command like

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=/path/ca.cer --tlscert=/path/client.cert --tlskey=/path/client.key -H=localhost:2376 ps
```

But when I run `docker ps` I get a `bad certificate` error since the various tls options from the above command are not passed to docker. I have spent a number of hours going through the docker website and can't find any options on how to set them.

I have set `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there a `DOCKER_CACERT` environment variable that docker would read if `--tlscacert` is not specified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those options should be set in the [docker daemon config file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file)

```
"tls": true,
"tlsverify": true,
"tlscacert": "",
"tlscert": "",
"tlskey": "",
```

> The `--config-file` option allows you to set any configuration option for the daemon in a JSON format.
>   By default, docker tries to load a configuration file from `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on Linux and `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json` on Windows.

On the client side, you need to set the [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/) variables:

For instance:

```
$ docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd dev
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\captain\.docker\machine\machines\dev
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=dev
# Run this command to configure your shell: copy and paste the above values into your command prompt
```

(Replace `dev` with the name of your machine)

Make sure `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` refers to a *folder* which includes your certificate.

Comment: this seems to  work for the daemon, but running `docker  ps` would run the local client so to speak, which would connect to the docker daemon. I have used the DOCKER_CONFIG environment variable to point to the same file so they both use the same certificates, but it still complains about `bad certificate` if I run without any CLI options for tlscacert etc.

Comment: @airtruk I have added the client side in the amended answer.